# Regex help instead of split in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement where i need to replace a substring.

Input string is:

```
true-[Test5]procedure4.spec@john:380733712-1
```

Expected output string is:

```
true-[Test5]procedure4.spec@X:380733712-1
```

The word john has to be replaced with the character X here. To do that i have implemented java code as below.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class Regex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> variableList = Arrays.asList("true-[Test5]procedure4.spec@mohan:180713133712267-1");
        for (String item : variableList) {
            if (item.contains("@") && item.contains(":") && item.split("@").length >= 1
                    && item.split(":").length >= 1) {
                StringBuilder firstString = new StringBuilder(item.split("@")[0] != null ? item.split("@")[0] : "");
                StringBuilder secondString = new StringBuilder(item.split(":")[1] != null ? item.split(":")[1] : "");;
                System.out.println(firstString + "@X:" + secondString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am newbie to regular expression. I would like to replace the above code with regular expressions using Pattern and Matcher in java.

Comment: `str = str.replaceAll("@[^:]+", "@X");`

Comment: `item.split("@").length` is a pretty inefficient way to count the number of `@`s in a string.

Comment: side note: this original algorithm could fail pretty spectacularly if you have more than one `:` in the address.

Comment: mohan, what is the expected output for `"true-[Test5]procedure4.spec@mohan:somestr:here:1"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
List<String> variableList = Arrays.asList("true-[Test5]procedure4.spec@mohan:180713133712267-1", "true-[Test5]procedure4.spec@Step2-1");
for (String item : variableList) {
    System.out.println(item + " => " + item.replaceFirst("@[^:]+:", "@X:"));
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Qvb9bR). Output:

```
true-[Test5]procedure4.spec@mohan:180713133712267-1 => true-[Test5]procedure4.spec@X:180713133712267-1
true-[Test5]procedure4.spec@Step2-1 => true-[Test5]procedure4.spec@Step2-1
```

**Details**

- `@` - a `@` char
- `[^:]+`  - a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching 1 or more chars other than `:`.

See the [online regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/9Df1RA/2).

You may also use a capturing group / backreference to avoid repeating `@`:

```
.replaceFirst("(@)[^:]+:", "$1X:")
```

That is helpful if you have to match more than `@`, e.g. `([@#])`, matching `@` or `#`.

Comment: the original algorithm required the presence of a `:` but you seem to have omitted it

Comment: @PatrickParker It may be put into the pattern: `.replaceFirst("@[^:]+:", "@X:")`

Comment: I have an element in the list true-[Test5]procedure4.spec@Step2-1 ,which should be ignored as it does not have collon(:) in it. How to handle these kind of scenarios

Comment: @mohan Yeah, you need `:` in the pattern.